# DB no longer inserting, ibdata1 4GB (max file size ?)

Tags: mysql, innodb

My MySQL database is no longer updating. I believe this may be because ibdata1 is 4294967295 bytes / 4 GB, and the storage medium partition has a 4GB file size limit.

How can I get MySQL to split into another ibdata automatically every 4 GB? I am using innodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new file to the innodb_data_file_path variable, like

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:4G;ibdata2:50M:autoextend
```

By the way, the best practice is to use the `innodb_file_per_table=1`, so that every table uses this one tablespace (separate .ibd file)